# Remove Ubuntu login screen from Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login-screen, xubuntu

I fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 then recently installed xubuntu-desktop on top of it as I don't like Unity's slowness.

Still when logging in it shows Ubuntu style login screen. Now I want to bring Xubuntu style login screen.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the clue from the post pointed out by @Stromson.

Just use this command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -g lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

I got Xubuntu style login screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want any of the Ubuntu applications and are good with just the Xubuntu defaults, you can use the command on this site: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexubuntu

Comment: I don't want to remove all Ubuntu applications. But I got the clue from the web page you pointed out and now put as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is to re-install using an xubuntu disc instead of ubuntu as the base.  Depending on how long ago you've done the install, and how many files/setting/etc you need to save, this might be the simplest way.

Comment: That is the last resort :)